# Правильная организация целостности данных в связи "многие ко многим"

Tags: mysql, sql

Товарищи, есть три таблицы: `user`, `work` и `user_work`, которая отвечает за связь "многие ко многим" между `user` и `work`. В таблице `user_work` есть два внешних ключа `user_id` и `work_id`, которые ссылаются на поля `id` в таблицах `user` и `work` соответственно, у обоих прописано `ON DELETE = CASCADE`.
Я попытался сделать так, чтобы при удалении записи из таблицы `users` автоматически сносились все связанные записи в таблицах `user_work` и `work`. Для этого пришлось перенести внешний ключ `work_id` в таблицу `work`, и заставить его ссылаться на `user_work.work_id`.
Собственно, вопрос в следующем: возможно ли теперь сделать так, чтобы можно было добавлять записи в таблицу `work`, не добавляя сперва запись в таблицу `user_work`?

Comment: Если у вас связь многие ко многим, то зачем вы хотите автоматически удалять записи из таблицы work, ведь могут оставаться записи других пользователей с той же work. Ее по хорошему можно удалять только триггерами, убедившись, что больше не осталось user  с этой же work.

Comment: Точно. Я тупой дегенерат. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> Я попытался сделать так, чтобы при удалении записи из таблицы users автоматически сносились все связанные записи в таблицах user_work и work. Для этого пришлось перенести внешний ключ work_id в таблицу work, и заставить его ссылаться на user_work.work_id.

Это неправильное решение. Правильное - написать `AFTER DELETE` триггер для таблицы `user_work`

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER user_work_ad AFTER DELETE ON work_work
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE `id` = OLD.`user_id`
  )) THEN
    DELETE FROM work WHERE `id` = OLD.`work_id`;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Ваш триггер не отвечает условиям связи "многие ко многим" он удалит запись work если не найдет удаляемого сейчас пользователя. А ведь могут быть записи других пользователей с тем же work !!!

Comment: @Mike по условию задачи "при удалении записи из таблицы users автоматически сносились все связанные записи в таблицах user_work и work"

Comment: Да, но условие задачи совершенно неверно сформулировано для связи "многие ко многим", что я указал в комментариях к вопросу и автор со мной согласился